# Error in form using acts-as-taggable-on

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, acts-as-taggable-on

I'm trying to implement acts-as-taggable-on on one of my rails models but I runt into a problem when trying to create the form. It complains that the method tag_list is undefined. Even though I can use it in the console. My model looks like this:

```
class Reflection < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_taggable
  attr_accessible :body, :title, :category_id

  validates_presence_of :category_id

  belongs_to :category
end
```

And my form like this:

```
<%= form_for(@reflection) do |f| %>
...
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label 'Tags' %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :tag_list %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

However when I try to load the form I get the error
    `undefined method 'tag_list' for #<Reflection:0x007fc1dbef08b8>`.

Anyone got any clues on what I can do?

Answer (score 0):

My bad, the server hadn't restarted after I added the gem..

Answer (score 0):

Just add **:tag_list** to **attr_accessible** like

**attr_accessible :body, :title, :category_id, :tag_list**